# Syncfusion ComboBox not working in stacklayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, combobox, syncfusion

I'm using trial version of syncfusion for testing.
I'm tring to use comboBox in an stackLayout but it won't show. as long as it fill the whole line it works but when i try to use it in an stacklayout it stop showing.
what should i do to use comboBox within an horizontal stacklayout?
this is my xaml code

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="T"/>
                <comboBox:SfComboBox />
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using a horizontal stacklayout it might not look proper it might get all crunched add a background color to the combobox and see if you still have it

Comment: @G.hakim i did try that but still nothing.

Comment: Trying using some other layout with it like grid or something

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a height request, so it will "reserve space" for displaying the ComboBox.

Check this example, you can change the value of HeightRequest according to your needs.

```
   <combobox:SfComboBox HeightRequest="40" x:Name="comboBox"/>
```